# MPRemoteCommandCenter play/pause Flashing when touched

Tags: swift, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

i'm working on music player app that written in `Swift`, audio streams with `AVPlayer` and everything is fine

but when i tried to add MPRemoteCommandCenter to my app there was a lot of bug that i dont know even why this happend

[link to video that describes my problem](https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5b62ebfc2f43c06b8a79a56d/5c10a2b3fe5bf03dc37c5db3/73dd1f706a1ef0fd336845757e6f6612/VID-20181231-WA0003.mp4)

### AVPlayer Implemented like:

```
func setupPlayer() {
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: musicURL)
    self.player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: item)
    self.player.play()
    self.player.volume = 1
    self.player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { (time) in
        if self.player.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
            self.reloadNowPlayingInfo()
            let currentTime = self.player.currentTime().seconds
            self.playingTime.text = currentTime.getTimeString()
            self.playerSlider.value = currentTime/duration
        }
    })
}

func reloadNowPlayingInfo() {
    var info = [String : Any]()
    info[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = self.titleText
    info[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork.init("some image")
    info[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = seconds
    info[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = currentSecs
    info[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = "Artist name"
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = info
}
```

---

and for command center,

### MPRemoteCommandCenter Implemented like:

```
func setupCommandCenter() {
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playCommand(_:)))
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pauseCommand(_:)))
}


@objc func playCenter(_ action: MPRemoteCommandEvent) {
    self.state = .play
    self.playBtn.setBackgroundImage("some image"), for: .normal)
    self.player.play()
    self.fetchTracks()
}
@objc func pauseCenter(_ action: MPRemoteCommandEvent) {
    self.state = .pause
    self.playBtn.setBackgroundImage("some image"), for: .normal)
    self.player.pause()
    self.fetchTracks()
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I've just run into the same problem...

Comment: @mohamad did you find a solution for this? i have same problem.

Comment: @RP-3 no same... , your answer was helpful once but when i tried again and removed `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` the player in lock screen goes away completely.

Comment: @Vipulk617 no.. i seen this in good apps like spotify too..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to the code you've presented you might also have called the following somewhere in your app delegate:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Doing this in addition to using `MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()` seems to cause a race condition.

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623126-beginreceivingremotecontrolevent):

> In iOS 7.1 and later, use the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter object to register for remote control events. You do not need to call this method when using the shared command center object.
>
> This method starts the delivery of remote control events using the responder chain.

Remove that method from your app delegate and you should be fine.